# Отсутствует меню Android в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Программа не печатает в log. Все говорят, что в меню Tools->Android нужно поменять настройки, но этого меню у меня нет. Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишите подробнее, что вы пытались делать(как пытались выводить в лог и тд), скрины прикрепите, что бы подробнее понять что там может быть не так

Comment: в какой именно лог не печатает?

Comment: вы в вкладке logcat смотрите?

Comment: Мне нужно Enable ADB Integration

Answer (score 1):

В новых версиях Android Studio (начиная с версии 3.3) нет отдельного меню *Android* в меню *Tools*. Теперь то, что было там, разбросано по другим меню.

На скриншоте вы можете посмотреть, что раньше было в меню *Tools -> Android*:

[image: scrn1]

Большинство пунктов этого меню теперь непосредственно в меню *Tools*.

Пункт *Sync Project with Gradle Files* теперь в меню *File*.

*Enable ADB integration* теперь включено всегда. Управлять подключением вы можете через *Connection Assistant*, нажав *Troubleshoot Device Connection* в меню *Tools*

*Theme Editor* был исключен из Android Studio, о чем есть [соответствующая запись](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119271605)

*Android Device Monitor* [был заменен](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor) инструментом [*Profiler*](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler). Попасть в него можно проследовав:*View -> Tool Windows -> Profiler* или в панели над строкой состояния внизу экрана (где выводятся логи), выбрав вкладку *Profiler*

Comment: Тогда почему logcat пишет no debuggable processes, если эмулятор есть?